# sum columns with different combinations in R?

Tags: r

```
X_0   X_1   X_3   X_6  X_12   Y_0   Y_1   Y_3   Y_6  Y_12                                                                                                   
<dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>                                                                                                 
0     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0                                                                                                 
0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     1                                                                                                 
0     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0                                                                                                 
1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0                                                                                                 
0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0                                                                                                 
0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0                                                                                                 
0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     0                                                                                                 
0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     0                                                                                                 
0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     1     1                                                                                                 
0     0     1     0     0     1     1     1     0     1
```

Below is a df

I want add the columns like in below format using R code

```
X0,Y0   X1,Y0   X3,Y0   X6,Y0   X12,Y0

X0,Y1   X1,Y1   X3,Y1   X6,Y1   X12,Y1

X0,Y3   X1,Y3   X3,Y3   X6,Y3   X12,Y3

X0,Y6   X1,Y6   X3,Y6   X6,Y6   X12,Y6

X0,Y12  X1,Y12  X3,Y12  X6,Y12  X12,Y12
```

I tried something like this but didn't work

For each x ==1, then count the number of 1s in the ys

```
apply(df[x.0==1, grepl(x=names(df),’y.’)],2,sum)]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you show `X0,Y0` and say *"For each x ==1, then count the number of 1s in the ys"* do you mean `df$X0 + df$Y0`, or `sum(df$X0 + df$Y0)`, or maybe `sum(df$X0 * df$Y0)`? Or something else? It would be clearer if you would show at least a few values of your expected result.

Comment: Sorry! if I was not clear,

What I want is this- sum(df$X0 + df$Y0) and for all combinations above.

I have a code below, where I need to insert the combo manually for each cell.

tes=df%>%filter(X_0==1&Y_1==1)%>%select(pid)%>%summarise(n_distinct(pid))
This code will give me the no of ppl with 1 for XOYO and for all combos.

I need a simplified code that can give me the result without any manual entry for each combo.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counting concurrent 1s in column pairs, we can use matrix muliplication:

```
xs = grep("X", names(df), value = T)
ys = grep("Y", names(df), value = T)

xm = as.matrix(df[xs])
ym = as.matrix(df[ys])
t(ym) %*% (xm)
#      X_0 X_1 X_3 X_6 X_12
# Y_0    1   2   1   0    0
# Y_1    0   2   1   0    0
# Y_3    0   0   1   0    0
# Y_6    0   0   0   0    0
# Y_12   0   0   1   0    0
```

Counting all 1s in column pairs:

```
xs = grep("X", names(df), value = T)
ys = grep("Y", names(df), value = T)

sums = colSums(df)

t(outer(setNames(xs, xs), setNames(ys, ys), FUN = function(x, y) sums[x] + sums[y]))
#      X_0 X_1 X_3 X_6 X_12
# Y_0   11  12  11  10   10
# Y_1    8   9   8   7    7
# Y_3    7   8   7   6    6
# Y_6    4   5   4   3    3
# Y_12   4   5   4   3    3
```

Using this data:

```
df = read.table(text = 'X_0 X_1 X_3 X_6 X_12 Y_0 Y_1 Y_3 Y_6 Y_12 
0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 
0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 
0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 ', header = T)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for bringing the output so close.

Comment: The above code is adding all the ones in X_0 and Y_0 separately (X_0=1+Y_0=10) which is 11. From each row I can count as 1 only if in that row X_=1 and Y_=1. So, my result should look like-> X0Y0=1, x1y0=2,X3Y0=1

Comment: Yes... that's why I asked what you meant. You said you wanted `sum(df$X0 + df$Y0)`, which means counting all the ones separately like I have done. But now you're telling me you actually want `sum(df$X0 * df$Y0)`. Thanks for providing the example results, that makes it much clearer and gives me confidence that we are now understanding each other.

Comment: Edited to add that solution. Please give example output next time to avoid confusion!

Comment: Thank you so much! Next time I will frame better and  I will post the output table too.