# Sum all possible combinations of columns in R

Tags: r, combinations, permutation

I have a data table (100 rows x 25 cols) that is structured like this:

```
     ColA ColB ColC ColD
1:      1    3    1    2
2:      2    2    1    2
3:      3    1    1    2
```

I want to add column values together, in every possible combination.

The output would include, for example:

ColA+B   ColA+C     ColA+D   ColB+C   ColB+D etc.

BUT! I don't just want pairs. I am trying to get every combination. I also want to see, for example:

ColA+B+C    ColA+B+D   ColA+C+D   ColB+C+D

And:

ColA+B+C+D

Ideally I could simply add all these permutations to the right of the base dataset (I am looking to do a correlation matrix on all these permutations.) I am far from an R expert.  I see there are packages like combinat - but they don't seem to get at what I'm after. I would be very grateful indeed for any suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: hi, might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71414751/sum-columns-with-different-combinations-in-r

Comment: Ugh - I'm sorry that my attempt to demonstrate the structure of the data basically totally failed. Hopefully makes sense anyway?

Comment: This is going to get very large. There are 33 million different combinations of columns to tabulate BEFORE you even try to run your correlation matrix. Are you sure this is what you want to do?

Comment: Ha! Thanks, Dan. It did occur to me that this would get massive, although I didn't actually run the permutations. (I always struggled with that at school.) I think I would probably end up cutting out some of the columns, and probably adding some additional criteria that I was (for the purposes of the correlation) I was only comparing columns of similar sizes (sums.) So I would look to limit it down a bit. But I don't think that changes the basic need for an algorithm that can pull alls these combos in principle. ? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm hesitant to present this as a suggestion: it works with four columns, but as @DanAdams commented, this explodes with 25 columns:

```r
choose(25,2)   # 25 columns, 2 each
# [1] 300
choose(25,3)   # 25 columns, 3 each
# [1] 2300

### 25 columns, in sets of 2 through 25 at a time
sum(sapply(2:25, choose, n=25))
# [1] 33554406
```

But, let's assume that you can control the number of combinations you need. Change `2:4` to be the number of combinations you need.

```r
combs <- do.call(c, lapply(2:4, function(z) asplit(combn(names(dat), z), 2)))
names(combs) <- sapply(combs, paste, collapse = "_")
length(combs)
# [1] 11
combs[c(1,2,10,11)]
# $ColA_ColB
# [1] "ColA" "ColB"
# $ColA_ColC
# [1] "ColA" "ColC"
# $ColB_ColC_ColD
# [1] "ColB" "ColC" "ColD"
# $ColA_ColB_ColC_ColD
# [1] "ColA" "ColB" "ColC" "ColD"

ign <- Map(function(cols, nm) dat[, (nm) := rowSums(.SD), .SDcols = cols], combs, names(combs))
dat[]
#     ColA  ColB  ColC  ColD ColA_ColB ColA_ColC ColA_ColD ColB_ColC ColB_ColD ColC_ColD ColA_ColB_ColC ColA_ColB_ColD ColA_ColC_ColD ColB_ColC_ColD ColA_ColB_ColC_ColD
#    <int> <int> <int> <int>     <num>     <num>     <num>     <num>     <num>     <num>          <num>          <num>          <num>          <num>               <num>
# 1:     1     3     1     2         4         2         3         4         5         3              5              6              4              6                   7
# 2:     2     2     1     2         4         3         4         3         4         3              5              6              5              5                   7
# 3:     3     1     1     2         4         4         5         2         3         3              5              6              6              4                   7
```

BTW: I'm inferring that your data is of class `data.table`, ergo the side-effect I'm using here. If that's not the case, then this is base R:

```r
dat <- cbind(dat, data.frame(lapply(combs, function(cols) rowSums(subset(dat, select = cols)))))
dat
#   ColA ColB ColC ColD ColA_ColB ColA_ColC ColA_ColD ColB_ColC ColB_ColD ColC_ColD ColA_ColB_ColC ColA_ColB_ColD ColA_ColC_ColD ColB_ColC_ColD ColA_ColB_ColC_ColD
# 1    1    3    1    2         4         2         3         4         5         3              5              6              4              6                   7
# 2    2    2    1    2         4         3         4         3         4         3              5              6              5              5                   7
# 3    3    1    1    2         4         4         5         2         3         3              5              6              6              4                   7
```

(Please don't blame me if your R crashes due to memory exhaustion. Save your work often.)

---

Data

```r
dat <- setDT(structure(list(ColA = 1:3, ColB = 3:1, ColC = c(1L, 1L, 1L), ColD = c(2L, 2L, 2L)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L)))
```

Comment: I won't blame you! Thank you so much. I appreciate the proposal very much, and also that both you guys have pointed out the combinatorial explosion which I was sort of too-casually ignoring. I plan to add one column at a time and keep saving as I go. Trying now.

Comment: Wow - this seems to work extremely well, and is so simple. Thank you!! I wish I understood this better. It seems like 'combn' is a key function here but I'll have to  dig into this more carefully. I will also start figuring out how to limit the combinations of columns. This is great - thanks again!

Comment: Indeed, check out `?combn`

Comment: Guys - This piece of the code: "data.frame(lapply(combs, function(cols) rowSums(subset(dat, select = cols))))" worked fine in my original code. Now, with a larger input data set and a goal of 28:30 combinations, this data frame has 377 observations of 0 variables. The original dataset is made up of all integers. Any idea why this would suddenly have crapped out? Any help much appreciated.